# Get NOT_FOUND with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring framework.
I try to make a simple web server application with Spring but I got 404 Not Found when I call url with Postman.

```java
package com.leoaslan.doctorfinder;

//..import

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request"})
@EntityScan("com.delivery.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.delivery.repository")
public class DoctorfinderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DoctorfinderApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
package com.leoaslan.doctorfinder.controller;


//import

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @GetMapping("/auth/login")
    ResponseEntity<?> login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("OK");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

I haven't configured anything yet in `application.properties`.

Thanks for any helps

Comment: what was in the HTTP request? Is the webserver running completely and no error?

Comment: Yes it's running completely and no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller class is not being scanned, so just try to add the proper package of your controllers on your @ComponentScan

```
@ComponentScan({"com.delivery.request", "com.leoaslan.doctorfinder.controller"})
```

Actually, do you really have those packages (com.delivery.request, com.delivery.domain, com.delivery.repository) on your application ? They look suspiciously copy/pasted and they will not do anything unless you change them where your classes really are.